# Change of bibtex style

Tags: bibtex, natbib

So I am preparing my thesis for my Master's project and our university has a little bit different referencing style than the standards. The closest standard bibtex style is 'abbrvnat' style.

Abbrvnat style is [First author name Initial.Last Name,Second author first name.Last Name,.....]

My required style is
[First author Last Name,First Name Initials., Second author Last Name,First Name Initials....]

So how do I achieve this style by modifying the abbrvnat.bst?

The rest of the style is the same. I just have to change the author naming style with last name first.

[image: example bibtex style]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you consider using `biblatex`? It's easier to customise, as it uses  a LaTeX syntax.

Comment: I have never heard of biblatex. I'll search it up and see if it serves my purpose. Thanks

Comment: Besides being easily customisable, it works by default with `biber`, which understands `utf8`, contrary to `bibtex`.

Comment: You write that one of the requirements is that `,` (comma) rather than `and` must be used as the separator between authors. Yet the screenshot you posted shows the exact opposite: the word `and` rather than `,` is used as the separator. Please clarify.

Comment: If there are two authors then they should be separated by 'and'. For more than two authors the authors should be separated by 'commas' and the last author by 'and'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows.

- Find the file `abbrvnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `abbrvnat-mod.bst`. (Don't edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `abbrvnat-mod.bst` in an editor. The editor program you use for your tex files will do fine.
- In the file `abbrvnat-mod.bst`, locate the function `format.names`. (In my copy of this file, the function starts on line 216.)
- In this function, locate the following line:

  ```
      { s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
      { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```
- Save the file `abbrvnat-mod.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution as well.
- In your main file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat-mod}`. Then, perform a full recompile cycle (LaTeX-BibTeX-LaTeX-LaTeX).

Happy BibTeXing!

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{ab:3001,
  author = "Anna Adele Author and Brenda Betsy Buthor",
  title  = "Initial thoughts",
  year   = 3001,
}
@misc{abc:3002,
  author = "Anna Adele Author and Brenda Betsy Buthor and Carla Christina Cuthor",
  title  = "Additional thoughts",
  year   = 3002,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat-mod}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll give this a try and check if it works out.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly. Saved me from manually typing each.